# UglifyJS 2: api equivalent for cli -m toplevel?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'm trying to convert the following command:

```
uglifyjs src1.js src2.js -c -m toplevel --screw-ie8
```

to an API call:

```
ug.minify(['src1.js','src2.js'], {mangle:true, compress:true, ie_proof:false})
```

But I can't figure out how to set 'toplevel'. Setting `toplevel:true` or `mangle:'toplevel'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `toplevel` option within object literals:

```js
require('uglify-js').minify(['src1.js','src2.js'], {
    mangle: {
        toplevel: true
    },
    compress: true,
    ie_proof: false
});
```